# How to integrate Flash SWF in Android app using Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, flash, air

I am trying to integrate Flash file in my sample Android app but couldn't make it?
I have also gone through Adobe AIR but seems like different than Android Studio developed app.

Comment: The easiest way is to use Adobe AIR. The language is ActionScript and should be easy to understand by a Java or C# coder... What does your app do? Maybe just build this one specific app with AIR and export APK file from there?